# Is there a way to make sure users use the latest Excel macros?

Tags: excel, vba, oracle-fusion-apps

I have a macro enabled excel workbook that employees in my firm use to upload data to our DB. The employees download the workbook from our firms Oracle UCM. The problem I'm facing is that after some enhancements and changes, many people are still using the previous version which end up causing errors at times such as some columns not being supported any more, etc. So is there a vba code that I can write to prevent uploads from old versions? The data is being uploaded by making REST API calls from the excel workbook.

Comment: We had a file on our server with the latest version number in it. The macro checked that file as its first task and it its own version number was not the same it would run the update task before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

1. Change your REST API so it can return a version number.
2. Make your macros read that version number.
3. If REST API number is higher than macros number it is incompatible and tells user to update.

This won't solve your actual issue right now but in future.

To kick off your current macros. Change your API so it requests to send a version flag or something from the macro. So it does not perform anything if it has not the above version check. This makes old macros not working anymore so people will at least call and ask why it is not working.